# How to design a String class with MaxLength?

Tags: c#, string, class, oop, object

I am planning to create my own string class, but it will have a max length provided.
Let's call it "lString".
I want to use "lString" just like a "string" class in my code. But I will be able to set a maxlength for it.

For example, this code should be built:

```
// 1- No maxlength provided, so the object will be created.
lString mylString1 = "0123456789";
// 2- maxlength provided, so it will be checked, and then created.
lString mylString2 = new lString("0123456789", 10);
// 3- This time only maxlength provided, so it will be a string object with maxLength.
lString mylString3 = new lString(20);

// At the end, I should be able to use it like a regular strings:
mylString3 = mylString1 + mylString2;

// Below should throw exception at RunTime, because it will be over 20)
mylString3 = mylString1 + mylString2 + mylString1 + mylString2;
```

Comment: And? Does it work?

Comment: I dont think this is possible. You are reassigning mylString3 so that would be a new value no matter what.

Comment: @AndersKjeldsen I reassign mylString3 just like you can assign a normal string. I am k with a new value.

Comment: case1 is doable with an implicit cast operator. Case 2 is possible. Case3 is.... ok. Its the reassigning that breaks this. once you assign `myString3 = ......` it knows nothing about the pre-assigned maximum. Would yo consider `var myString3 = new lString(myString1 + myString2, 20)` to be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: You can't use it to extend string, string is a sealed class, an extension is at least what you can do or just a Interface that does all string operations from here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its fairly trivial to implement a basic string class which has implicit operators to and from a normal string:

```
public class LimitedString
{
    private readonly string value;
    private readonly long maxLength;

    public LimitedString(string value, long maxLength = long.MaxValue)
    {
        if(value != null && value.Length > maxLength)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Value is longer than max length");
        this.value = value;
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        if(o is LimitedString)
            return value == ((LimitedString)o).value;
        return false;
    }

    public static implicit operator LimitedString(string str)
    {
        return new LimitedString(str);
    }

    public static implicit operator String(LimitedString ls)
    {
        return ls.value;
    }        
}
```

And then your first 2 cases work as expected:

```
LimitedString myString1 = "0123456789";
LimitedString myString2 = new LimitedString("0123456789", 10);
```

However, the only way you can make your third example work is like this:

```
LimitedString myString3 = new LimitedString(myString1 + myString2 + myString1 + myString2, 20); // Throws exception
```

As once you re-assign the value your specification of the max length is lost, so you cant do this:

```
LimitedString myString3 = new LimitedString(20); // This is fine - you could have a constructor that just takes the max length.
myString3 = myString1 + myString2 + myString1 + myString2; // but here you're re-assigning.
```

Live example: https://rextester.com/KVBBQT19360

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. Only one thing needs to be fixed. This 2-line code should throw an exception:  LimitedString myString2 = new LimitedString("0123456789", 10);
            myString2 = "01234567890123456789"; You see, myString2's maxLength was set as 10 already. Now we are trying to set it for 20 char string. We shouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: @HakanErdogan you didnt read the end of my answer - thats not possible, you're re-assigning `myString2` to a **completely different instance to the one which had the `maxlength` set**.

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was a working sample. I will mark it as an answer, as there is no other way.